# Doctrine - Multiple inserts in foreach with prepared statement

Tags: php, doctrine

I want to do something simple with doctrine. I need to use `INSERT IGNORE` and therefore I use native SQL to send multiple queries to the database. I want to add certain email addresses to the database. I did this:

```
$qb = $this->modelManager->getConnection()
    ->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO `unsubscriber`
            (email, listId) VALUES (:email, :listId)');

    foreach (array_keys($unsubscribedMembers) as $email) {
        $qb->bindValue('email', $email);
        $qb->bindValue('listId', $listId);
    }
$qb->execute();
```

This results in the last email address being inserted into the database.

When I fire the execute inside the foreach loop, it's only the first email address that is added to the database. When I initialize the $qb also inside the foreach each time, also only the first email address is added to the database.

How can I add all email addresses in `$unsubscribedMembers` to the database using native sql here?

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, you are binding the values in the foreach, so the last iteration (email) will get binded and then only 1 'INSERT' query is executed. Move the execute call in your foreach. That way, the query will get executed for every email in the array.

```php
foreach (array_keys($unsubscribedMembers) as $email) {
    $this->modelManager->getConnection()
        ->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO `unsubscriber` (email, listId) VALUES (:email, :listId)')
        ->bindValue('email', $email)
        ->bindValue('listId', $listId)
        ->execute();
}
```